# List all users based on array of domains

Tags: users

I would like to display a list of any users whose emails are detected to have email addresses from an array of domains.

`$domains = array('domain1.com', 'domain2.com', 'domain3.com');`

If any users match those domains they would be listed in an un-ordered list, such as:

`user1@domain1.com 
user2@domain1.com 
user3@domain3.com 
etc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code which return object of matched records with user_email column into wordpress database users table.

```
/*
        This function will return object of all match user records
        Function Location : themes/function.php
*/
function get_domain_user($domains){
        global $wpdb; 

        //Build query for match records selection using RLIKE
        $strdomain = '';
        foreach( $domains as $domain ) : 
                if($strdomain == ''){ 
                        $strdomain = "'" . $domain;
                }
                else {
                        $strdomain = $strdomain . "|" . $domain;
                }
        endforeach; 
        $strdomain = 'user_email RLIKE ' . $strdomain . "'";

        //Execute query for pull all respected records...
        $strQuery = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->users WHERE $wpdb->users.$strdomain";
        return $user_query = $wpdb->get_results($strQuery);
}
```

Call this function like:

```
//Email address domain array...
$domains = array('domain1.com', 'domain2.com', 'domain3.com');

//Pull records which users email address contain $domains mail address...
$user_list = get_domain_user( $domains );
```

If there is any issue/doubt/concern regarding this please contact me.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but it could get you started:

```
function get_users_list_by_domain_array($domains)
{
     $final_list = [];
     foreach( $domains as $domain )
     {
          $blog_id = get_blog_id_from_url($domain);
          if( ! $blog_id ) continue;
          $users = get_users(['blog_id'=>$blog_id]);
          $list = array_map(function($user){
               return $user->user_login.'@'.$domain;
          },$users);
          $final_list = array_merge($final_list,$list);

     }
     return $final_list;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
global $wpdb; 

$domains = array('domain1.com', 'domain2.com', 'domain3.com');
$str  =''; //Initialize string;
for($i=0;$i<count($domains);$i++)
{
    if($i == count($domains)-1)
    $str.= " user_email like '%{$domains[$i]}' "; //Build sql query to match email domain
    else
    $str.= " user_email like '%{$domains[$i]}' or ";    

}


$users = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->users WHERE $str"); //This will return list of users with matching email domain
echo "<ul>";
foreach($users as $user)
{
echo "<li>$user->user_login</li>"; //Print users
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: Please add a proper explanation to your code. Please see [answer]